# Use existing variables when using refetchQueries in react-apollo

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, prisma-graphql

I am using `postsConnection` query for infinite scroll. It contains variables like `after`.
After doing an upvote mutation, I want to `refetchQueries`... like this

```
const upvote = await client.mutate({
      mutation: UPVOTE_MUTATION,
      variables: {
        postId: this.props.post.id
      },
      refetchQueries: [
        { query: POST_AUTHOR_QUERY }
      ]
    })
```

Above code gives error because `POST_AUTHOR_QUERY` accepts few variables. Here's that query

```
export const POST_AUTHOR_QUERY = gql`
    query POST_AUTHOR_QUERY($authorUsername: String! $orderBy: PostOrderByInput $after: String){
        postsAuthorConnection(authorUsername: $authorUsername orderBy: $orderBy after: $after) {
                   ....
        }
    }
```

*I do not want to add variables manually. Variables are already stored in the cache. How do I reuse them while using `refetchQueries`???*

*Here are a few resources I have read about this issue*

https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/817

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1900

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in [the issue you linked](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/817), you should be able to do the following:

```
import { getOperationName } from 'apollo-link'

const upvote = await client.mutate({
  // other options
  refetchQueries={[getOperationName(POST_AUTHOR_QUERY)]}
})
```

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching#after-mutations):

> Please note that if you call refetchQueries with an array of strings, then Apollo Client will look for any previously called queries that have the same names as the provided strings. It will then refetch those queries with their current variables.

`getOperationName` simply parses the document you pass it and extracts the operation name from it. You can, of course, provide the operation name yourself as a string instead, but this way avoids issues if the operation name changes in the future or you fat finger it.

Comment: That fills one variable `authorUsername` as needed. But `after` variable seem to be blank.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to pull in `apollo-link`, you can also get this via the base `graphql` package (note that I use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for convenience:

```js
import { getOperationAST } from 'graphql';


const operationName = getOperationAST(POST_AUTHOR_QUERY)?.name?.value;
// Note that this could technically return `undefined`

const upvote = await client.mutate({
  mutation: UPVOTE_MUTATION,
  variables: {
    postId: this.props.post.id
  },
  refetchQueries: [operationName]
})
```